# Releasing linux software - compatibility

Tags: c++, glibc

I want to release a C++ library for Linux. Is it true that (when no other libs are dynamically linked) only the glibc version decides compatibility to other Linux distributions?

Is there a better way to support most Linux distributions of the last 5 years than setting up several virtual machines and compiling there? For example, will a Linux binary that has been compiled on a very old Linux system run on new Linux versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux's kernel APIs are very stable. (I'm talking about the system calls, not the APIs inside the kernel.) A statically linked executable produced since 1997 or thereabouts (the switch to [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) as the executable format) should work on any current Linux systems. However, statically linked executables have many downsides: they're bulky, they can't be upgraded easily when bugs are found in a third-party code, and they tend to live in their own bubble as they have trouble interacting with some system features for which the standard library provides configurable support (e.g. DNS, locales, user accounts, …).

For libraries, a common convention is that the a change in the first number in the version indicates an incompatible ABI change, and the rest of the version increases on backward compatible changes. So for example, if your program is linked against version 2.3, it will work with version 2.3 or 2.4 of the library but not with 2.2 or 3. Some libraries use different conventions. The dynamic linker uses the [soname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) recorded in the library to decide whether its version is suitable.

The standard library on non-embedded Linux is [Glibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library). The major version of Glibc has been 6 on Linux (so it's known as libc6) since about 1998; the upstream major version is 2, which explains why the version of libc6 is 2.*MINOR* and not 6.*MINOR*. In principle, programs linked with older version of libc6 should work with more recent versions, though this wasn't always true early on. Any program linked with Glibc 2.3 or above should work on current versions.

The standard C++ library used to change more rapidly, but the current major version (6) has been current since about 2005.

If you compile a program on an older system, it should work on newer systems, provided that the required library versions are available. Take the [oldest supported version of CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/Download) (currently 5) and the [oldest [old]stable Debian release](https://www.debian.org/releases/) (currently wheezy, though squeeze might still qualify); if you produce a binary that runs on both, it's likely to work on all Linux installations (excluded embedded systems and ones that are running obsolete versions for which security updates are no longer available).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mostly, although you may need to avoid new kernel features.

If you wish to create a portable C++ program it is advisable to adhere to the official ISO C++ standard.  As the standard gets changed, you may need to adapt your program but that is usually not a lot of work.

You can ask g++ to keep to an older standard to avoid your program not compiling on a machine with an older library.  Defines for the compiler look like

```
-D__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_ISOC99_SOURCE=1 -D_ISOC9X_SOURCE=1
```

(for C).

Of course, there is also the hardware issue (target CPU including architecture like IA64, and CPU features like SSE).